# Unable to process binding order summary at cart page Magneto 2.1.7

Tags: magento-2.1.7

Having below error at my cart and checkout page and shipping cost, in summary, is continuous loading.
[image]

[image]

> knockout.js:3012 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding
>   "foreach: function(){return $parent.getRatesForGroup($data) }"
>   Message: Unable to process binding "css: function(){return {'field
>   choice item':available,'message error':!available} }" Message:
>   available is not defined
>       at css (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.js:2624), :3:84)
>       at update (knockout.js:3803)
>       at ko.dependentObservable.disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved (knockout.js:3004)
>       at evaluateImmediate (knockout.js:1737)
>       at Object.ko.computed.ko.dependentObservable (knockout.js:1946)
>       at knockout.js:3002
>       at Object.arrayForEach (knockout.js:151)
>       at applyBindingsToNodeInternal (knockout.js:2974)
>       at applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal (knockout.js:2854)
>       at Object.ko.applyBindings (knockout.js:3065)

Comment: if you have customized your checkout then please update your code in question.

Comment: I am using amasty onepage checkout

Comment: did you customize that?

Comment: no. My support period is expired.